# how to send a message with a attachment to Teams through Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Microsoft has provided updated API for sending messages to channel in Teams.

[Post Message in Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-chatmessage?view=graph-rest-beta)

after this update, now we can give importance, mention the user in sending a message to Teams.

curious to know, can we send messages with attachment in this new update?

have a look on below link for the chatMessageAttchment resource type that is used for sending a message with an attachment.

[chatMessageAttchment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatattachment?view=graph-rest-beta)

I want to know what all we can be achieve in this new endpoint.

`POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages`

Comment: Currently only [application/card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatattachment?view=graph-rest-beta#properties) type is supported.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently supported, I'll add a note to the docs clarifying this.